How to implement custom deserialization for a DOM-like type containing non-serializable resources?
I'm implementing a unified parameter extractor Params for axum that can handle parameters from Path/Query/Form/Multipart. I have a custom DOM-like type that stores both JSON data and uploaded files:
pub struct UploadFile {
    pub file_name: String,
    pub temp_file: Arc<NamedTempFile>,
}

pub enum ParamsValue {
    Object(HashMap<String, ParamsValue>),
    String(String),
    UploadFile(UploadFile),
}

I need to deserialize ParamsValue into a struct like this:
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct FileUploadParams {
    title: String,
    file: UploadFile,
}

The challenge is that the UploadFile field(or just temp_file field) needs to be assigned directly from ParamsValue::UploadFile variant rather than being deserialized. I've tried implementing Deserialize/Deserializer traits for both ParamsValue and FileUpload, but can't get it working.
Any suggestions on how to implement this custom deserialization properly?

UPDATE:
Note: I've simplified the ParamsValue enum by removing irrelevant variants (JSON/Array) to focus on the core problem.
This implementation aims to provide Rails-like structured parameters in Rust, where parameters from various sources (path/query/form/multipart) are parsed into a tree-like object structure. For example, form fields with names like user[name] or user[profile][avatar] are parsed into nested ParamsValue::Object nodes, with UploadFile being one type of leaf node in this tree.
I've already implemented the parameter tree construction part - the code successfully builds the nested structure from various parameter sources. The current challenge is implementing the deserialization from this tree structure into user-defined types, basic types are easy to implement, I don't know how to transfer a resource type (UploadFile here), maybe a workaround is save the path and then re-open it in deserialization, but I don't want that.
let mut params = HashMap::new();
params.insert("title".to_string(), ParamsValue::String("test".to_string()));
params.insert("file".to_string(), ParamsValue::UploadFile(UploadFile {
    file_name: "test.jpg".to_string(),
    temp_file: Arc::new(NamedTempFile::new().unwrap()),
}));

FileUploadParams::deserialize(ParamsValue::Object(params))


Surely to customize ser/de, implementing those traits are required. There is always a way; at the end of day, we can send byte codes. Please share what you've done.

I updated more details.
